# getElementsByTagName vs jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

What would the version of this be in jquery?

```
document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].innerHTML;
```

I need help converting this in order to fit into my `$.get` request:

```
$.get( 
    link, 
    function(data) {
        var res = $(data).find("pre").html();
        console.log(res);
    }
);
```

Comment: http://vanilla-js.com/

Comment: What are you getting in the console log ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---

The *exact* [JQuery equivalent] would be `$('pre').eq(0).html()`.  The sortof-ish mix with non-JQuery would be `$('pre')[0].innerHTML`

### How's it work?

`$('pre')` returns an Object with all elements with a tag name of `pre`

`.eq(0)` gets the first element in the array.

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7xsUs/1/)**

---

Since you're getting the first item, `$('pre').first().html()` also works.

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7xsUs/2/)**

---

Another thing that works would be just `$('pre').html()` (Credit to RobG)

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7xsUs/3/)**

---

Please note that  JQuery's `html` method is not identical to a browser's `innerHTML` property but it's the JQuery equivalent (Credit to **RobG**).

---

Comment: `$('pre').html` is less to type, though jQuery's *html* method is not identical to a browser's *innerHTML* property but it's the jQuery equivalent.

Comment: @RobG Added it to answer

Answer (score 2):

Here it is in jQuery:

`$('pre').first().html()`

Answer (score 0):

Simply specify the element name in the selector:

```
$("pre").html()
```

It's not necessary to explicitly select the first element. From the [API docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

> If the selector expression matches more than one element, only the
>   first match will have its HTML content returned

Answer (score 0):

If you only need one element, give the element and ID and pull it by ID

```
document.getElementById("ID")
```